# How to input value based on radio button change in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipywidgets

I need to get user input based on the radio button option selected. I want the function to be triggered on radio button changed. It works but when I add **input** to get response from user, it throws an error.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display

questions=widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['YES', 'NO'],
    value=None,
    description='Search By:',
    disabled=False)


def bind_selected_to_output1(sender): 

        selected_option=questions.value
        ##here input from user is required that will be later used. 
        input_value=input("Please Enter a valid number")
        print('Selected option set to: ' + selected_option+input_value) # For test purposes
        
        
questions.observe(bind_selected_to_output1, names=['value'])
questions
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear example, I don't think you can achieve what you want to do using input here, the widgets code doesn't seem to want to wait for you to enter input. You might be better off with a widget free text field or drop down with your options, and then a button to click to set your option, rather than mixing `widgets` and `input`.